# Whoisguard for Icelandic TLD?

Tags: domain-registration, whois, privacy

I have an .is domain name registered with ISNIC. Every bit of my information (name, email, address) shows up when doing a whois and I'd like to avoid that.

I can't find anything relating to Whoisguard on their website. I also have a Namecheap account but apparently they don't handle .is domains.

Any idea on if this is possible?

Comment: Not every extension allows privacy, I can't find anything what-so-ever about whether it is allowed/disallowed, I also checked some of their Registrars and I couldn't really find anything that way either.  So I would suggest you just contact their support team and ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: in "My Settings" one must only set "Address withheld" to "Yes". This will hide all information related to the postal address, except the country code (not such a big deal).

The registrant information, which my guess is ISNIC requires it correct, will appear in the whois database. Therefore I don't think there's a way of hiding one's name...

Answer (score 1):

With some TLDs e.g. .au, it is not possible to implement domain privacy.

I can't comment on .is (it may be worth investigating) but with .au domains when there was a domain transfer issue that saw registrant address info not included with the domain, the registry advised that it wasn't a problem as there is no rule stating that whois information has to be accurate.

As long as the email address gets mail to you (you could set up one especially for the domain registration) then you may be OK to enter slightly obfuscated address info.  You live in Main St?  Change it to Mane St.   Change the house number.  etc.

In all my years as a domain reseller I have *never* heard of postal address info ever being used for anything apart from spam.  Perhaps the .au registry knows this and it is why they don't care so much about accuracy.

Comment: Thanks! I finally found there was an option to "withheld" the postal address. I was looking everywhere for Whoisguard and didn't consider that option at first...

Answer (score 0):

In my 10+ years experience I recommend

1. Setting a **deadline for privatizing your contact info** on the `.is` domain (i.e. 1 week)
2. *If you can't accomplish this with Namecheap*; start looking at new hosting and domain providers.

Some hosting companies will even migrate it for free if you call their Customer Support.

Comment: "deadline for privatizing your contact info" What do you mean? As a personal deadline, or is it something to be set with the registrar?

Comment: A personal deadline. Again, from experience you can call a company like GoDaddy and have them migrate this all for you (assuming they handle `.is` TLDs).